# How much greater is the average distance between stars in the spaces between spiral arms? How much lower is it in them?

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, galaxies

I've read about the overall average distance between stars in the milky way, and I've read that one of the best explanations for spirals arms is that they are density waves - that is, they are indeed denser than the spaces between them.

Do any estimates exist for how much denser stars are distributed in arms, or how much less densely they are between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stellar density in spiral arms is not much larger than in-between the arms, typically only a factor of 1.5–3 (e.g. [Rix & Rieke 1993](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1993ApJ...418..123R); [Antoja et al. 2011](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2011MNRAS.418.1423A/)).

Since the mean distance between particles of number density $n$ is proportional to $n^{-1/3}$, the interstellar distance in-between the spiral arms is actually of the same order as inside the arms, typically a few tens of percent, up to perhaps 50% greater.